# Is there a way to implement video streaming in PhoneGap on Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, video-streaming

Is there a way to implement video streaming in PhoneGap on Android?

I need to implement a live video/TV stream on Android and iOS with PhoneGap. But I cannot get Android/iOS to show the stream.

Does anyone know what format the stream needs to be in or how I can fix this (perhaps there's a plugin?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jplayer plugin in :
http://jplayer.org/

or use phonegap plugin like this tutorial
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Comment: hi,my problem is related to this question.Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718171/how-to-use-trendnet-ip-camera-live-streaming-url-in-phonegap-app