# How to use Trendnet Ip camera live streaming url in Phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, ip-camera

I am making phonegap app in which i am using **trendnet ip camera** to show live streaming.
To watch **live streaming** i have this url **http://xx.xx.xx.xx:100/video/mjpg.cgi**.
I am using this as

```
<img src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:100/video/mjpg.cgi" />.
```

On web browser it is working fine and in android  app it is not working.

How do I accomplish this?

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: try whitelisting the url

Comment: i have used <access origin="*" />.Is it ok ??

Comment: yes, that should whitelist all the urls.

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks.But i already have done that.Its not working

Comment: @jcesarmobile Should i share my url with you?

Comment: did you try on the mobile android browser?

Comment: yes,not working in android browser.

Comment: then there is nothing you can do... if the browser doesn't support it, cordova don't support it

Comment: Do you have any other idea to get live video from ip camera in mobile?

Comment: no idea, it deppends on the camera, some of the stream in compatible formats, but .cgi isn't one of them, maybe with an intermediate server such as wowza media server or flash media server that picks the .cgi and converts it to other format like apple http live streaming

Comment: @jcesarmobile ,it works in chrome mobile browser.

Comment: then it might work on android 4.4 and greater. Or you can try crosswalk project too https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: yes it is working on android 4.4

Comment: then try project crosswalk, it's a chromium webview and should work there too

Comment: Please use crosswalk project

Comment: @masadi zainul  I am trying Crosswalk project and getting an issue . I explained problem in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091574/error-while-migrating-cordova-app-in-crosswalk

Comment: @jcesarmobile Can you please have a look into this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640322/cordova-media-player-error