# Error while Migrating Cordova app in CrossWalk

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am trying to **migrate cordova app** in **Crosswalk** using ***command line tools*** as given in [this](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html#Migrate-using-command-line-tools) tutorial.After running **android update project --subprojects --path . \
    --target "android-19"**
MY terminal shows:

*Updated project.properties*

*Updated local.properties*

*build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.*

*Added file ./proguard-project.txt*

*Updated project.properties*

*Updated local.properties*

*build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.*

*Added file ./xwalk_core_library/proguard-project.txt*

After that i followed rest of the steps given in documentation.
And after installing app on android device it crashes shows message (Unfortunately app has stopped).
I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you build the projects in the given order:

1. xwalk_core_library
2. CordovaLib
3. YOUR PROJECT

Follow the commands as provided here(https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html#Migrate-using-command-line-tools)

$ android update project --subprojects --path \ --target "android-19"

$ ant debug

$ cd ../../..

$ cordova build android