# Cordova Media Player error

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to play video from webserver in cordova app. I tried multiple plugins but none of them are working for me at the moment.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-video-player

and 
https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media

but both of them are not working for me.

Here is the code.

```
function playvideos(){

 VideoPlayer.play(
    "https://www.teztertb.xyz/video/T3_1512322360.mp4",
    {
        volume: 0.5,
        scalingMode: VideoPlayer.SCALING_MODE.SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
    },
    function () {
        console.log("video completed");
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
}
```

also i tried another code for second plugin.

```
function playvideo() {

   var videoUrl="https://www.mysite.xyz/video/T3_1512322360.mp4";
          console.log('local url      :'+videoUrl);
          var options = {
            successCallback: function() {
              console.log("Video was closed without error.");
            },
            errorCallback: function(errMsg) {
              console.log("Error! " + errMsg);
            }
          };
          try
          {
           window.plugins.streamingMedia.playVideo(videoUrl,options);
         }
         catch(Error)
         {
             console.log("error from server or local"+Error);
         }

      }
```

I make some changes in config.xml as below.

```
 <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

and added code in index.html file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```

I am not sure what to do next because all the time i am getting some error. I also tried youtube videos but that is also not playing.

I am getting below error.

cordova Media Player Error: Unknown(1) - 1005

cordova Media Player Error: Unknown(1) - 1004

Comment: Whitelist shouldn't affect native plugins, so it's more likely to be a codec problem or a server certificate problem. Not sure if you first url is a real url, but I can't load it on my browser

Comment: @jcesarmobile If I try local path then it works. Url is working fine in browser. Unfortunatly I can't share it. But if i play youtube videos that is also not working.

Comment: First plugin looks like it's for local videos, second one should work for streaming. Can you try with http instead of https so you can discard server certificate problems? Youtube links are not really video files, so it's not strange that it doesn't work. You can try with big buck bunny video `http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4`

Comment: Trying now give me 5 min.

Comment: Well i tried the above link. I am getting below error. Error! MediaPlayer Error: Unknown (1) -1005

Comment: Seems to me this link is invalid. http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuc‌​kBunny_320x180.mp4 Try to open it on your side. I am getting 404

Comment: http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work when pasted as code, click on the link now, it should work

Comment: @jcesarmobile well it is very painful because i thought we can play video easily in cordova but its fifth day i didn't have any luck.